# How to access Data from Sql In MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

What is present scenario of Retrieve data from SQL in MVC 4 or 5.

Is it safe to use Entity FrameWork?.

disadvantage of using Entity FrameWork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe to use entity framework, and is probably the most recommended method to begin with.

Comment: Can i use ADO.Net Entity Data Model to access data? or use define Table class manually.?

Comment: Yes, if you already have a database defined, you can add an ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

Comment: It is fine if you are using EF6 and have an already existing database.

Comment: what about using Sqlconnection ?

Comment: EF will handle the connection for you, as well as providing the necessary classes for your tables.

Comment: Yes, you can use EF for real time projects.  Most performance issues when reading data is due to Change Tracking being enabled when it is not required to be, but all this can be configured.

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET Entity Framework: [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**For the Best Practice, Try this link to begin with.**

1. EntityFramework Tutorial:
   [EntityFramework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/)
2. MSDN Tutorial to integrate EntityFramework in Project:
   [MSDN](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: what about using Sqlconnection ?